# Remote Oracle Database Successfully Connected to BIRT But Tables Are Not Showing

Tags: database, oracle, eclipse, birt

I have connected a remote oracle database by its **IP address** in **BIRT** through A **VPN network**. It shows the **connection successful** but **tables are not showing** just Stored Procedure are showing there.

Is there any solution? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons could be:

- Did you check the "Prefetch all schemas from database" and "Enable SQL code assist" checkboxes in the same JDBC Dataset preferences?
  I think hat tables are only shown when these are checked.
- What you think is a TABLE is a SYNONYM instead. Synonyms are only shown when the "Show   Aliases" checkbox in the DataSet edit dialog is checked.
- Or it's a VIEW. Check the "Type" listbox in the DataSet edit dialog.

Anyway, while developing reports for a schema with about 1000 objects (tables, views, synonyms, packages etc) everyday, I have switched the options "Prefetch all schemas from database" and "Enable SQL code assist" off, and I don't miss it at all.

Instead, as a best practice:

I always develop and test my SQL queries with Oracle SQL*Developer (using bind variables of the form :PI_XXX) and then just copy/paste the query into BIRT's DataSet edit dialog.

Each bind variable exists exactly once in the query. This is strictly necessary, because internally, BIRT/JDBC replaces each :PI_XXX bind variable with a "?".

Each bind variable corresponds to a BIRT DataSet parameter. The order of the DS parameters must correspond to the order of the bind variables in the query.

In order to be able to use a bind variable several times in a query, I use the WITH PARAMS AS (SELECT ... FROM DUAL) trick:

For example:

```
with params as
(   select :PI_PATTERN as pattern
         , to_date(:PI_FROM_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY')      as from_date_incl
         , to_date(:PI_UNTIL_DATE, 'DD.MM.YYYY') + 1 as until_date_excl
    from dual
)
select t.MY_ID
     , t.ENTRY_DATE
     , t.DESCRIPTION
from   my_table t
     , params
where  (params.pattern is null or t.description like params.pattern)
and    (params.from_date_incl is null or params.from_date_incl <= t.entry_date)
and    (params.until_date_excl is null or t.entry_date < params.until_date_excl)
order by t.MY_ID
```

Comment: I have checked "Prefetch all schemas from database" & "Enable SQL code assist". All are ticked but still, tables are not showing. Just "Stored Procedure" is showing.

N.B: I have connected a remote oracle database using an IP address with a VPN network.

Comment: Depending on the size and number of your database's schemas, querying ALL_OBJECTS (as BIRT probably does to fill the tables list) may be just too slow.

Comment: I have connected the database with a VPN network. Is it could be a fact?

Comment: Just stored procedure are showing there but not any tables. I have also connected the database in Oracle SQL Developer. All tables are successfully showing in SQL developer! I got confused why it is not working in BIRT.

Comment: You should ignore this issue and instead focus on if a query that works in SQL*developer (as a simple test, something like "SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL" works in BIRT.

Comment: Not a single table is shown in BIRT. How could I query like this in BIRT? I couldn't get your answer. Would you please explain in brief.

Comment: Use SQL*Developer with the same DB account as in BIRT to test your query. Then just copy/paste the SQL text into the BIRT dialog. Run your report. Look for error messages.